# Euclidean division of two counters

Tags: counters

I'd like to print the remainder of the Euclidean division by `4` of a latex counter. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it that you are actually looking for calculating *a* mod *b*. There is probably a wide range of options how to solve this. Using Expl3 syntax, you could do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentCommand{\remainderofdiv}{ m m }{
        \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \remainderofdiv{5}{2}

    \remainderofdiv{12}{2}

    \remainderofdiv{12}{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So, given that you have a counter that contains *x* and now you want to output *x* mod 4:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentCommand{\mycountermodfour}{ }{
        \int_mod:nn { \value{mycounter} } { 4 }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \setcounter{mycounter}{7}
    \mycountermodfour

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

In OpTeX, you can use `\expr` macro:

```
\def\remainderofdiv#1#2{\expr[0]{#1\%#2}}

\remainderofdiv{12}{5}

\bye
```

or, you can use `\directlua` directly:

```
\def\remainderofdiv#1#2{\directlua{tex.print(#1\%#2)}}
```

If you want to implement `\mycountermodfour` then you can use the previously defined macro:

```
\newcount\mycounter
\def\mycountermodfour{\remainderofdiv{\the\mycounter}{4}}

\mycounter=7
\mycountermodfour

\bye
```